# Unable to properly create nested hash after reading data from Excel

Tags: ruby, excel, hash

There is one quiz excel sheet which has 3000 questions.which has question_no, options, test_name, category, question_text,correct_answer,tags fields.  using "Spreadsheet" gem i have parsed data from excel.
Now I have one hash which stores "tags type" as key and tag related questions are stored in an array as value.

```
if questions_hash[tags_string] == nil
questions_hash[tags_string] = []
questions_hash[tags_string].push question
```

which look like this,

```
tags = {"tag1" => [value],"tag2" => [value] }
```

and other hash is,

```
categories = {"cat1" => "", "cat2" => "" }
```

and i want to assign tags hash as a value in categories hash.like

```
categories = {"cat1" => {"tag1" => [value], "tag2" => [value]} ,"cat2" => {"tag3" =>[value] }}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: want to create nested hash. i have two different hashes.

Comment: Malav: The solution I provided should work with ease. Cheers!!!

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking.  Does `questions_hash` look something like this: `{"good questions" => {"tag1" => arr1, "tag2" => arr2}, "bad questions" => {"tag3" => arr3, "tag4" => arr4}}`, where `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` and `arr4` are arrays of strings (questions)?  Please edit your question to clarify this; do not try to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash does has `push` method.

To insert value into Hash use simple assignment as:

```
questions_hash[tags_string] = question
```

Similarly, if you want to insert `questions_hash` as value to `catetory` hash use:

```
hash['History'] = questions_hash
```

That's it.

Comment: i just edit my question is this solution work for that also?

Comment: @malav: Yes this solution will work. Let me know if it doesn't. :)

Comment: How are you reading excel data?

Comment: @malav: Don't know where your issue is? Please edit your question mentioning I have this excel with these columns, i am using this gem, I got so far, want this but not getting. Conversation through comments will be blocked after some time so better to edit question to get good responses.

Comment: @malav: Do you multiple tags under column 'tags'? like 'tag1, tag2, ...' in one cell? If yes, I suppose you want same question to be present in two different 'tags'?

Comment: yes.but this categories and tags pair should be unique.